# How to close cmd window when batch file running exe

Tags: batch-file, exit

A very basic question, sorry.
How do I close a batch file CMD window after a command to run a exe is running in it's own separate window?  I mean even a trivial example like below?  The window doesn't close until notepad.exe (in this case) is closed.

```
"c:\windows\notepad.exe"
EXIT
```

I tried various cmd parameters but just can't get the window to close.  Be gentle!

Comment: It's a simple one liner: ```@Start "Text Editor" "%SystemRoot%\notepad.exe"```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the start command to start a program and continue your batchfile without waiting for the started program to finish.

```
@echo off
start "" "c:\windows\notepad.exe"
exit /b
```

See the help for **start** and **exit** for the details on using these commands.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I can get that working for a path that doesn't have spaces in, but not if it does.
I'm trying to run this - E:\Eagle Dynamics\DCS World OpenBeta\bin-mt\DCS.exe within a batch file and then close the command window.
If I do 
start E:\Eagle Dynamics\DCS World OpenBeta\bin-mt\DCS.exe it doesn't like the space between Eagle and Dynamics.
If I do 
start "E:\Eagle Dynamics\DCS World OpenBeta\bin-mt\DCS.exe", it doesn't like it at all.
If I cd to the folder and then do 
start DCS.exe everything is OK.

Comment: Start sometimes fails if you omit the first parameter (title). So it is best to always use as first parameter or a title "title" or an empty string "" as I have done in the code above. Depending on the program you start it may be necessary to include the /d "path" parameter. See the help for start for the details.

Comment: So basically @imacken, use the afvice you've been given, not something completely different, then complain about that instead.

Comment: @Compo have no idea what you are talking about, so I'll just ignore your comment.

Comment: I'll spell it out for you @imacken. You were given a solution, but instead of copying it, you changed it, then you complained it did not work for some files. The reason for that failure was **only** because you did not copy it. Ignoring the facts, does not make you any less culpable.

Comment: @OJBakker thank you for your help yesterday. That did the trick. Sorry, I’m new here and a couple of my comments to you yesterday didn’t get posted. Must be something I wasn’t doing correctly! Thanks again for your time.